# CiviMail Not Saving Changes to Email Drafts

Tags: civimail, email

My changes to a CiviMail draft are not visible when I try to come back to the same draft within the same web browser. However, if I open up the CiviMail campaign in a different web browser, those saved changes are visible.

Please see this link for an example of the issue:

http://screencast.com/t/7XKAveHrlDZv

We're running Joomla 3.4.5 and Civi 4.6.8. We have tested this on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox with the same results.

I recently updated to Civi 4.6.10 and we're still experiencing the issue. This only occurs when selecting the "Save Draft" button and does not seem to be a broswer caching issue, as we've tried to clear the cache without success.

Any help or suggestions woudl be appreciated.

Comment: Does this bug appear during "autosave" as well, or only when you click the "save draft" button?

Comment: I'm guessing it might be a caching issue. In your primary browser, when viewing the mailing (with changes incorrectly not showing) try a force-refresh (cmd-shift-r on a mac or ctrl-shift-r on a pc) and see if it brings up the correct draft. Not suggesting that as a full solution, but would be useful for pinpointing the problem.

Comment: Thanks Coleman! I've added some updates to my original post that answer your questions. Any additional thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That video was very helpful.  I don't have a solution, but a few more troubleshooting questions:
* In the video, it looks like your first browser was Chrome, the second was Safari.  Does the problem happen when you start with Safari and go to Chrome?
* If you view the underlying HTML of your message in the first browser, can you see your changes?

Comment: I have seen what may be related problems. Issue created at: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18016